# Check if has class

Tags: jquery

This is my html:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="somethingelse"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="somethingelse"></div>
    <div class="item active"></div>
    <div class="somethingelse"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Now, for each `item` I want to add the number in a div, so I did this:

```
function initMenu() {
    $( ".gallery-menu" ).html("");
    var columns = $('.item').length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < columns; i++ ) {
        $( ".gallery-menu" ).append( i );
    }
}
initMenu();
```

Now I get simple `0 1 2 3` in my `gallery-menu` div which is good.

Now I want to check if it is `active`. So I added a check like this:

```
function initMenu() {
    $( ".gallery-menu" ).html("");
    var columns = $('.item').length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < columns; i++ ) {
        if ($(".item:eq(i)").hasClass('active')) {
            $( ".gallery-menu" ).append( i + "-active");
        } else {
            $( ".gallery-menu" ).append( i );
        }
    }
}
initMenu();
```

But it's not working.. Someone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way would be to use jQuery's `each()` function:

```
$('.item').each(function(i, el){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $( ".gallery-menu" ).append( i + "-active");
    } else {
        $( ".gallery-menu" ).append( i );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
if ($(".item").eq(i).hasClass('active')) {
```

You can use `eq` function instead of concating the string.

Answer (score 2):

You missed to concatenate your `i`

Try this

```
if($('.item:eq('+i+')').hasClass('active'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to concatenate your `i` variable properly here using `+`:

```
if ($(".item:eq(" + i + ")").hasClass('active')) {
```